# Proving an encrypted message contains (but does not 100% consist of) a plain-text message?

Tags: encryption

I have keypair (u,r), and two pieces of data, X and Y.

I reveal X publicly but keep Y secret. Y has high entropy.

I then combine X and Y, into c(X,Y) = Z.

I encrypt Z, into "encrypt(Z,u) = Q".  r is needed to decrypt Q back into Z.

Can I prove (including interactive zero-knowledge proofs) that Q contains X, without revealing r or Y?

Please help! Thank you very much.