# Proving an encrypted message contains (but does not 100% consist of) a plain-text message?

Tags: encryption

I have keypair (u,r), and two pieces of data, X and Y.

I reveal X publicly but keep Y secret. Y has high entropy.

I then concatenate X and Y, into Z.

I encrypt Z, into "encrypt(Z,u) = Q". r is needed to decrypt Q back into Z.

Later, (when it doesn't matter), r will be revealed and everyone will decrypt Q into Z. At that point, everyone will know that, all along, Q "contained" X. Can I prove that Q contains X before r is revealed (including interactive zero-knowledge proofs)?

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought this was crypto.stack (oops). I am actually hoping that it will be impossible to prove that Q contains X (but I wanted to ask neutrally), are you saying that the only way to do this is to change the setup to force-include additional commitment constraints?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What does it mean for the function $c$ to combine $X$ and $Y$ into $Z$? Do you just mean concatenate? What does it mean that $Q$ contains $X$? Do you mean that $Q$ encrypts a message which has information on $X$?

Comment: Will you still have the randomness that was used for the encryption? $\:$ Can the verifier assume that the keypair was generated honestly? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Well, with the encryption-randomness kept and the keypair assumed to have been generated honestly, most PKE schemes will allow such proofs. $\;$

Comment: I experienced some kind of glitch when this question was moved here ( http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27789/proving-an-encrypted-message-contains-but-does-not-100-consist-of-a-plain-tex ) , and lost control of it.

Comment: Well, with the encryption-randomness kept and the keypair assumed to have been generated honestly, most PKE schemes will allow such proofs. $\;$

Comment: Thanks! I'd actually prefer it to be impossible to prove. If I multiply instead of concatenate ( X * Y = Z ), does that help (make it harder)? Does the choice of keypair matter (for example ECDSA)?

Comment: Definitely, since ​ 0*1 = 0 = 1*0 ​ and ​ 0 ≠ 1 . ​ ​ ​ [Somewhat bideniable](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/684.pdf) PKE schemes will make it infeasible to prove anything about the plaintext. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Ah great, thanks very much. When r is revealed, Y will be as well, so it will be trivial to divide {X*Y} by Y and get X. That paper seems very relevant, plausible deniability is key to my scheme. Thanks again.

Comment: However, I strongly encourage you to think hard about the _point_ of what you're planning, and whether using somewhat bideniable PKE would undermine that. $\;$

Comment: Can you edit in the info you posted? You should be able to now. Then just flag the answer below where you provided the info and I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental theorem of cryptography (Goldreich, Micali and Wigderson 1986) states that any NP statement can be proven in zero knowledge. So, the answer is yes. For **any** polynomial-time combination of $X$ and $Y$ into $Z$, it is possible to prove that $Q$ contains $X$ in zero knowledge.

Note that the general zero knowledge will not be practically efficient since it requires a Karp reduction. However, depending on the combination and the public-key scheme, it may be possible to do this very efficiently. El Gamal specifically is very amenable to efficient zero knowledge, but it depends on the combination you mean.

Comment: Why does it follow that the answer is yes?$\:$ (Unless somewhat bideniable PKE is known to be impossible, it's not clear to me that there must be an NP algorithm with a non-negligible probability of accepting encryptions of Z and a negligible probability of accepting encryptions of strings other than Z.) $\hspace{1.61 in}$

Comment: The ciphertext is a deterministic polynomial-time function of the plaintext (which contains X and other things) and the randomness. Thus, the NP statement is the public key and the ciphertext, and the witness is simply the plaintext and the randomness. (It's also possible to use the private key as the witness.) It appears that you are concerned with SOUNDNESS; what's stopping the prover from claiming it's a different plaintext, as you can do with non-committing types of encryption. It wasn't clear to me that this is a requirement. If it is, then you just need to use a committing encryption.

Comment: The OP would "actually prefer it to be impossible to prove". $\;$

Comment: In that case, the question isn't well enough defined. Do you want to make it impossible to prove but also impossible to open to something else later on? This is certainly not possible. I need a better definition of the soundness requirements.

Comment: Ideally it would be impossible to prove, during "Phase 1". During this phase, Y and r are both kept secret (and feel free to use r as a symmetric key if that matters).

During "Phase 2" (approximately 10-30 minutes later) everything is revealed: X, Y, and r.

I'd be happy to explain more, but am worried it would distract. The setting is a kind of voting, I want the votes ("X") to be secret while they're being cast because I'd like people to be able to lie about how they intend to vote (after the vote, it doesn't matter).

Comment: You are considering the topic of "no coercion" in voting. This property means that it's impossible to be coerced or to sell your vote, since you can lie about what you voted and it looks consistent to everything. Is this correct?

Comment: @Terrace : $\:$ If r can be a symmetric key, then you can just use the one-time pad. $\hspace{1.22 in}$ Explaining more would be helpful. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: More or less "no coercion". The trick to this problem is that the incentives of the user change twice: Phase 0 he prefers to be unable to "sell" his vote, Phase 1 he wants to go back on this promise, and actually sell his vote (especially if other people are selling), and Phase 2 he no longer cares about keeping any of the keys, votes, etc secure. So the major problem is that he might *prepare* in Phase 0 in a number of ways that leave him the option to share his vote in Phase 1 (even though he'd prefer everyone to be unable to do that). Does that help? Thanks guys for the responses!!

Comment: @Terrace : $\:$ Can you just use a one-time pad for the encryption? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I've been reading about the OTP. I think no, because you have to commit to your vote. It seems that you can just change the vote "X" after the fact by changing the OTP. But thanks for the suggestion, very interesting. I've been trying to figure out if works if the vote also contains a hash of its future OTP (Z = X + Y + hash(OTP), 3 things now), but I'm confused on the malleability point.

Comment: @Terrace: $\;\;\;$ Well, using somewhat bideniable PKE also won't give commitments to the votes. $\:$ (Accordingly, "you have to commit to your vote" should've been mentioned much earlier.) $\hspace{1.03 in}$